# Android : TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE not found

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to get the temperature from the phone. I have gone through the docs and found out
that `'TYPE_TEMPERATURE'` is deprecated since API level 14.
It is suggested to use `'TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE'`.
But I am unable to find this when I type 'Sensor.' , The auto completion does not show `'TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE'`.

Is there anything I am missing, any info would be helpful.

Comment: Make sure your target API level set to 14 or higher

Answer (score 2):

Your Phone should have temparature sensor to make it work.

Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.androidsensorbox&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImltb2JsaWZlLmFuZHJvaWRzZW5zb3Jib3giXQ..) ,check and confirm that you have temparature sensor.

[image]

Comment: I think the API has to provide it anyways right!! (I mean irrespective of the device/phone)

Answer (score 1):

`'TYPE_TEMPERATURE'` was designed to measure the CPU temperature and is likely deprecated because the new `'TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE'` is measuring external temperature and may be of more use. If you're using API level 14, `'TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE'` exists and will compile.